# Data sources not updating with ADO.NET Data Model

Tags: c#, silverlight, ado.net, wcf-ria-services, ado.net-entity-data-model

So I am creating a dashboard with C#/Silverlight. The dashboard is hooked to a remote database with a data model and a domain service. In my database I created a new view, and have added it to the data model. For some reason, after adding it to the data model, it does not show up in the data sources in visual studio 2010. Why is that? I tried refreshing the data sources but that didnt work. Any ideas?

I feel like this should probably be fairly simple to solve, but I think I have been staring at it for too long today, haha. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: How did you add it to the data model?  Through the wizard?

Comment: Yes, it was through the wizard.

Answer (score 0):

Well it appears I have fixed the problem. I just had to delete the .edmx file and the domain service and recreate it. Then it added everything to the data sources properly.